# Disable caddy ssl to enable a deploy to Cloud Run through Gitlab CI

Tags: docker-compose, api-platform.com, google-cloud-run, caddy

I am trying to deploy api-platform docker-compose images to Cloud Run. I have that working up to the point where the image starts to run. I have the system listening on port 8080 but I cannot turn off the https redirect. So, it shuts down. Here is the message I receive:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

run: loading initial config: loading new config: loading http app module: provision http: server srv0: setting up route handlers: route 0: loading handler modules: position 0: loading module 'subroute': provision http.handlers.subroute: setting up subroutes: route 0: loading handler modules: position 0: loading module 'subroute': provision http.handlers.subroute: setting up subroutes: route 1: loading handler modules: position 0: loading module 'mercure': provision http.handlers.mercure: a JWT key for publishers must be provided
```

I am using Cloud Build to build the container and deploy to Run. This is kicked off through Gitlab CI.

This is my cloudbuild.yaml file.

```
steps:
- name: docker/compose
  args: ['build']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['tag', 'workspace_caddy:latest', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/apiplatform']
- name: docker
  args: [ 'push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/apiplatform']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'erp-ui', '--image', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/apiplatform', '--region', 'us-west1', '--platform', 'managed', '--allow-unauthenticated']
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_php
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s

  pwa:
    build:
      context: ./pwa
      target: api_platform_pwa_prod
    environment:
      API_PLATFORM_CLIENT_GENERATOR_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy

  caddy:
    build:
      context: api/
      target: api_platform_caddy
    depends_on:
      - php
      - pwa
    environment:
      PWA_UPSTREAM: pwa:3000
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost, caddy:8080}
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY:-!ChangeMe!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY:-!ChangeMe!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp

  database:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=api
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
      - POSTGRES_USER=api-platform
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # you may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./api/docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw

volumes:
  php_socket:
  db_data:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

Comment: Can you share how do you deploy your cloud run? And your container ?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: And your compose configuration? There is someting wrong in the container building=

Comment: I have updated my question with the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Are you building a container? From where does this name `workspace_caddy:latest` come from?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps. https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/pull/3284

Comment: I could not find a config for that in apip but in api/config/packages/framework.yaml i found # See https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy#headers. Not that the reverse proxt itself is relevant but there may be more docs at caddyserver.com. 

BTW, according to docker-compose.yml the client generator already uses port 80, it seems the caddy has a vhost on http://caddy/ 
API_PLATFORM_CLIENT_GENERATOR_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy

Comment: I have the same problem.